# Accessing variables in a class

Tags: python

Could you help explain why it doesn't work and how to make it work?

```
class test():
    var1 = 0
    def subfunc(self):
        global var1
        if var1 == 0:
            print(var1)
        
test().subfunc()
```

Then the error is

```
NameError: name 'var1' is not defined
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your code? Why not to use instance field var1 in your class?

Comment: `test.var1` is *not* a global variable; it's a class attribute.

Comment: `var1` is not global. Use `test.var1` to access this value in the method `subfunc`.

Comment: `class` statements are tricky: they don't define a new scope, but they do define a new *namespace* that only lasts until the `class` statement completes.

Comment: Hi @user2976612 the original codes are for a leetcode recursive solution and I got quite confused on the variable access inside the DFS functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's breakdown your code by parts

```py
class test():
    var1 = 0  # class variable 1 
    def subfunc(self):
        global var1  # global variable 2
        if var1 == 0:  # trigger errors 3
            print(var1)
        
test().subfunc()
```

1. This is a `class variable`, it stays with `class`, if you update it, you update for all the object that is under this class.

```py
# if outside the class
class test():
    var1 = 0  # class variable

test.var1 += 1

# if inside the class
class test():
    var1 = 0

    @classmethod
    def increment_var1(cls):
        # it updates the class variable when called
        cls.var1 += 1

    def some_func1(self):
        self.increment_var1()
```

2. This is a `global variable`. In another words, this is outside your class scope and can be shared by another class if they are under the same scope.
   If there is a global variable defined in your module, it will reference that global variable and update.

```py
# variable already exists
c = 0 # global variable

def add():
    global c  # it references the global variable above
    c += 2
    print(c)
```

```py
# variable doesn't exists already, it will create a new global variable.
def no_meaning():
    global c
    c = 0  
    if var1 == 0:
        print(var1)
```

3. You encounter error because you don't assign a value to the `global variable`, so it doesn't have a value to reference to.

Conclusion:

1. If you want to update a class variable, you should update it by the referencing from class.
2. If this is a global variable, you should create it on the top of your file. This is very confusing to use the same name with the class variable, so this is advisable to use a different name.
3. If you want the variable stick with your instance, you should create it from `__init__` function

```py
SHARED_VAR = 0

# global variable
class S():
    def increment(self):
        global SHARED_VAR
        SHARED_VAR += 1

# class variable
class C():
    var = 0  #  class variable
    @classmethod
    def increment(cls):  # only update class variable
        cls.var += 1

    def instance_increment(self):  # only update instance variable
        self.var += 1

# instance variable
class I():
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = 0

    def increment(self):
        self.var += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `global` for a variable defined within a class, which means it is an instance variable.

The correct way to use this is:

```
class test():
    var1 = 0
    def subfunc(self):
        if self.var1 == 0:
            print(self.var1)
        
test().subfunc()
```

Comment: `self.var1` works (for this simple example) if you only want to read the value, but if you want to set the value you have to use `test.var1`.